# select unique GROUP_CONCAT-ed rows based on different column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, unique-key

Given table can have following rows.

i.e. for a given `filename`, there can be two unique `version_id`(s).

```
file_id    version_id      filename
1          OS_v1           abc.update
1          App_v1          abc.update
2          OS_v2           xyz.update
2          App_v2          xyz.update
3          OS_v1           abc(1).update
3          App_v1          abc(1).update

PRIMARY KEY (`version_id`, `filename`)
```

How to detect there are no two different filename's having same combination of OS_App (versions) ?

In the given example, row set with `file_id=3` is a duplicate of `file_id=1`.

Note: It's easy to define separate columns for OS and App version, but that requires a lot of code change which we dont wanted to go through.

Question: is there a `SELECT` query which would return just `file_id = 1` and `file_id = 2` and omit `file_id = 3` ?

So far I have come up with this query which selects a combination of `version_id` grouped by `filename`, but row-2 is a duplicate of row-1

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(GROUP_CONCAT(version_id SEPARATOR '-')) ,
         filename
FROM     schema_name.table_name
GROUP BY filename;
```

Returns :

```
concat_version patch_filename
OS_V1-APP_V1   xyz.update
OS_V2-APP_V2   abc(1).update
OS_V1-APP_V1   abc.update
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` natively supports `DISTINCT` keyword like so `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT version_id SEPARATOR '_')` try that instead.. `GROUP_CONCAT` even supports a `ORDER BY` clause see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Is there a SELECT query which would return just file_id = 1 and file_id = 2 and omit file_id = 3

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can take advantage of window function `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT x.file_id, x.version_id, x.filename
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY version_id ORDER BY file_id) rn
    FROM master_logs.system_patches t    
) x
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

The inner query assigns a row number to each record in `version_id` groups, ordered by `file_id`, and the outer query filters in records with row number `1`.

---

With earlier versions of MySQL, one typical solution is to use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to filter out unwanted records :

```
SELECT t.file_id, t.version_id, t.filename
FROM master_logs.system_patches t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM master_logs.system_patches t1
    WHERE t1.version_id = t.version_id AND t1.file_id < t.file_id
)
```